# Layoutproblem with custom listitem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am using a layout for the rows of my custom list. In this layout I have an image to the left and on the right side 2 text boxes on top of each other. I would like to have the top textbox to be split in two. Like this:

```
-------------------------------
|    |  Topleft  |  Topright  |
|ICON|-------------------------
|    |  bottom                |
-------------------------------
```

I already have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But this isn't working. I get it to work with only one toptext but not with two. Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the `orientation` of the LinearLayout with `topText` and `topText2` to `"horizontal"`. Since `"horizontal"` is the default orientation you can remove the entire attribute:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

However if you aren't using long strings in your TextViews, you might be able to use one RelativeLayout instead of three LinearLayouts.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does the job. Why do you strongly recommend the RelativeLayout?

Comment: I only noticed your extensive use of `layout_weight` after writing... However you might be able to use 1 RelativeLayout instead of 3 LinearLayouts to achieve the same result, this all depends on the length of the text you place in each TextView.